# i want to use the outputs as data and sum them

Tags: python, pandas, output

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('test_python.csv')
print(df.groupby('fifth').sum())
```

- this is my data

[image: data]

**And I am summing the first three columns for every word is in fifth.
The result is this and it is correct

[image: results]

The next thing I want to do is take those results and sum the together
example:

```
**buy = 6
cheese = 8
file = 12
.
.
.
word = 13**
```

- How can I do this? how can I use the results.**
- -And also now,  want to use the column second as a new column with the name second2 with the results as data, how can I do it?

[image: results]

Comment: Please show your data in text rather than images.

Comment: please refer to the Stackoverflow guidelines  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example  Include data as a code (preferably) over text

Comment: first second third forth fifth
1 1 0 one hello
1 2 0 two no
1 3 0 three yes
1 4 0 four hi
1 5 0 one buy
1 6 0 two bye
1 7 0 three cheese
1 8 0 four water
1 9 0 one ham
1 10 0 two juice
1 11 0 three file
1 12 0 four word
1 13 0 one world
1 14 0 two red
@ifly6

Comment: sorry new to this @Naveed

Comment: df.to_dict() and then post the resulting dictionary in the question

Answer (score 0):

For Summing you can use apply-lambda ;

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"first":[1]*14,
                   "second":np.arange(1,15),
                   "third":[0]*14,
                   "forth":["one","two","three","four"]*3+["one","two"],
                   "fifth":["hello","no","hello","hi","buy","hello","cheese","water","hi","juice","file","word","hi","red"]})
df1 = df.groupby(['fifth'])['first','second','third'].agg('sum').reset_index()
df1["sum_3_Col"] = df1.apply(lambda x: x["first"] + x["second"] + x["third"],axis=1)
df1.rename(columns={'second':'second2'}, inplace=True)
```

Output of df1;

[image]

Comment: i want to sum the results i already have not the data, the results i am getting from the sum i want to sum them @sachin kohli

Comment: Yeah I know.. after groupby assuming you got df as your data frame you can use this code... edited the answer... is it what you are looking for ?

Comment: That's right @Naveed... It's just got used to this apply-lambda... That ended up using it... :) Thanks for your input...

Comment: @SachinKohli the result you posted yes is correct is the result i want. the code is not working , and also what i am trying to do not to wire the whole data down, is just to take them from the output and sum them